# Python numpy array slices are not Fortran Contiguous

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, f2py, contiguous

I have defined a Fortran contiguous array:

```
   import numpy as np

   hp  = np.zeros([number_fragments, max(length_fragments_list), 6], order='F')
```

Slices of this array are not Fortran contiguous. How can I fix that?

```
hn = hp[0,0:Length-1,:]

   hn.flags

  C_CONTIGUOUS : False

  F_CONTIGUOUS : False

also

   hn = hp[0,0:Length-1,:].copy()

   hn.flags

  C_CONTIGUOUS : True

  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
```

How can I get, easily, Fortran contiguous arrays after slicing?

Comment: I usually don't pay attention to the `flags` attribute.  Understanding the `strides` is better.  Sometimes I also look at `hn.__array_interface__`.

Comment: Thanks. unfortunately, when I send the sliced array to a Fortran wrapped function, it says the input is not Fortran contiguous. So, it needs fixing.

Comment: With 'F' order the last dimension is the outer one.  Indexing like `hp[:,:-1, 0]` keeps the 'F' continuity (but would break 'C' continuity of an initially 'C' array).  `copy` takes an order parameter.

Answer (score 5):

You can apply the numpy function `np.asfortranarray` on your slice to enforce it, example:

```
 np.asfortranarray(hp[0,0:Length-1,:].copy())
```

Comment: @DavoodNorouzi, cool, don't hesitate to validate/lvl up the answer so ;)

Comment: Is the `copy` needed after `asfortranarray`?  I think `hp[0,0:Length-1,:].copy(order='F')` would also work.

Comment: @hpaulj, `asfortranarray` alone, from what I experienced, don't copy the value. So yes, your solution seems to be more appropriate in the case where a copy of the array is needed.

Comment: The actual code is `np.array(a, dtype, copy=False, order='F', ndmin=1)`.  `copy=False` means don't copy if you don't have to, but you may if needed.