# Numpy Concatenate Produces array whose slices are non F-Contiguous?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython, contiguous

**Background**

I'm passing large matrices into a Cython function which in turn calls the BLAS routine `dgemm`. I've been pulling my hair out for 15 hours trying to understand why the BLAS output is not in line with `np.dot`. I've narrowed it down to the `f_contiguous` flag on any slice of on one of my input arrays.

Although on the face of things the array shows as `f_contiguous`, any slice that I take (which will be passed into the BLAS routine is in fact not `f_contiguous`, which it needs to be for the `scipy.linalg.cython_blas` wrappers.

I'm new to both Cython & calling Fortran routines so I wouldn't be surprised if there is some glaring oversight on my part.

In **Example** I take a list of `(4, 4)` arrays (with fortran contiguity) and concatenate them into a `(4n, 4)` array. Because concatenate does not have an `order` argument, I must then tell create a new array from the concatenated one using F `order`. This produces the issue in which the array itself is `f_contiguous` but any 2D slice I take from it is not.

**Example**

```
n = 10
arr_list = [np.eye(4, order='F') for _ in range(n)]
arr_concat = np.concatenate(arr_list)
arr_f = np.array(arr_concat, order='F')
print('Array F-Contiguous? {}'.format(arr_f.flags.f_contiguous))
print('2D Array Slice F-Contiguous? {}'.format(arr_f[0:5, :].flags.f_contiguous))

Array F-Contiguous? True
2D Array Slice F-Contiguous? False
```

**Discussion**

This issue is similar to the one [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57927933/python-numpy-array-slices-are-not-fortran-contiguous). The solution to me seems to construct a list of lists using comprehension. Then calling `np.array(order='F')` on the nested list. Or iterating through the array and forcing each section to be `f_contiguous`. But this doesn't seem elegant to me, and I'd like to avoid it because these matrices may get quite large. This function will be called tens of thousands of times so I need to make the process as fast as possible.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: `arr_f[:,0:5]` should be f_contiguous.  with `arr_f[0:5,:]` you are selecting half of each column, in effect every other blocks of 5 elements.

Comment: @hpaulj I just realized this! Now I'm trying to figure out how to circumvent this. Think about passing a list of array pointers to cython, rather than a concatenated array.